# How to show that the class number is bounded by Minkowski's bound?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and let $M$ be the Minkowski's bound. We can say that each ideal class in the ideal class group $Cl(K)$ has an ideal $I$ with $N(I) < M$. By this fact, how can we say that  $h_K < M$?
I am not sure that if any two integral ideals has the same norm, they belong the same class or not. If it is, then we are done.

Comment: Who says that $h_K<M$?

Comment: Are there any counter examples?

Comment: A cursory search shows that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-194})$ has class number $20$, but Minkowski bound $\sim 17.5$

Comment: Can you give me some reference, please?

Comment: I found it on [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/), although you could compute the class number using the Minkowski bound? ;)